# How can I take snapshots from webcam in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, camera, html5-canvas, html5-video, webrtc

How can I take snapshots from webcam in Internet Explorer 11? Is there a plugin for that purpose? I tried Temasys WebRTC Plugin but it just made access to webcam which replace video tag to an object element. And from an object I cannot take snapshot to a canvas.

Comment: [This demo](http://addyosmani.github.io/getUserMedia.js/face-detection-demo/index.html) will do what you want. It uses flash and I tested it in IE 11 and it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you use webcam .js for webcam snapshot it will work with IE

please use this link
https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 (or any IE for that matter) does not support WebRTC. Microsoft announced that they will support ORTC in a future version of IE but it's not here yet. So you hands are pretty much tied. You have to use flash.